# Trying to change entries in dataframe raising key error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have created a dataframe called autos from [this dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/orgesleka/used-cars-database/data).
I have 3 columns in this dataframe which haves dates as entries. I want to remove remove the hours minutes and seconds part of the date.
Example:

```
data = [["2016-03-24 11:52:17"], ["2016-03-24 10:58:45"], ["2016-03-14 12:52:21"]] 
auto = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['date_crawled'])
```

Output:

```
          date_crawled
0  2016-03-24 11:52:17
1  2016-03-24 10:58:45
2  2016-03-14 12:52:21
```

I thought I could do this by creating the following function, which would take in a date column and format it.

```
import datetime as dt
def datetimeconv(date_column):
    for i in range(0,371528,1):
        for elements in auto[i,date_column]:
            elements=dt.datetime.strptime(elements,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            elements=elements.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
            auto.loc[i,date_column]=(elements)
```

When I tried to test it out on the `date_crawled` column:

```
datetimeconv("date_crawled")
```

I got the following error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3077             try:
-> 3078                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   3079             except KeyError:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: (0, 'date_crawled')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-71-2e8c9398d8c4> in <module>
      6             elements=elements.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
      7             auto.loc[i,date_column]=(elements)
----> 8 datetimeconv("date_crawled")
      9 

<ipython-input-71-2e8c9398d8c4> in datetimeconv(date_column)
      2 def datetimeconv(date_column):
      3     for i in range(0,371528,1):
----> 4         for elements in auto[i,date_column]:
      5             elements=dt.datetime.strptime(elements,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
      6             elements=elements.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2686             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
   2687         else:
-> 2688             return self._getitem_column(key)
   2689 
   2690     def _getitem_column(self, key):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _getitem_column(self, key)
   2693         # get column
   2694         if self.columns.is_unique:
-> 2695             return self._get_item_cache(key)
   2696 
   2697         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _get_item_cache(self, item)
   2487         res = cache.get(item)
   2488         if res is None:
-> 2489             values = self._data.get(item)
   2490             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)
   2491             cache[item] = res

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in get(self, item, fastpath)
   4113 
   4114             if not isna(item):
-> 4115                 loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
   4116             else:
   4117                 indexer = np.arange(len(self.items))[isna(self.items)]

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3078                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   3079             except KeyError:
-> 3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   3081 
   3082         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: (0, 'date_crawled')
```

Why am I getting a key error?

Comment: Please, in addition to the Kaggle link, post an excerpt of the dataset that reproduces the issue.

Comment: As in post the first few rows of the dataframe?

Comment: Yes, in machine readable form, so that I can reproduce your dataframe

Comment: Is posting the first few rows of the relevant columns not acceptable? There are many other columns that are not relevant to the question.

Comment: Of course only the relevant columns. But the examples you posted are not machine readable and who knows hat `dtype`.

Comment: Sorry for still not understanding, but how do I make my example machine readable? I have already posted the code I input and its output. What else do I have to do?

Comment: Post Python code that *creates a dataframe*.

Comment: in `for elements in auto[i,date_column]:` you're iterating **over the individual characters of the string** entry. See my anwer below for a pandas like solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason for KeyError:

You must use `df.loc[i,'date_crawled']` instead of `df[i,'date_crawled']`. The latter tries to select a column (series) with a hierarchical index (multiindex) by the tuple (i,'date_crawled'). Such a column doesn't exist in your dataframe, hence the KeyError.

The normal pandas way to do it is:

```
auto['date_crawled'] = auto['date_crawled'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))
```

Alternatively, as Nils Werner remarked in his comment, also:

```
auto['date_crawled'] = pd.to_datetime(auto['date_crawled']).dt.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
```

---

To anser your question why your code doesn't work (besides the KeyError): in `for elements in auto.loc[i,date_column]` you iterate over the individual characters in each entry. The following would be a working version:

```
def datetimeconv(date_column):
    for i in range(0,len(auto)):
            elements=auto.loc[i,date_column]
            elements=dt.datetime.strptime(elements,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            elements=elements.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
            auto.loc[i,date_column]=(elements)
```

**However, never iterate explicitely over dataframe rows, use pandas methods whenever possible. This code is just to illustrate where your error was.**

Comment: In the last line of my function i wrote `autos.loc[i,date_column]=(elements)` is this not the same?

Comment: There is no need for `apply()` here: `df['date_crawled'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_crawled']).dt.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")`

Comment: Thank, good point. In the meantime I rephrased it a bit, however, to make it easier to understand.

Comment: Just a question about the error. I understand that I was iterating over the characters, but why does that raise a key error? I wouldve thought it would give the element does not have the format specified error, when making element a date time object.

Comment: @V.Jain see the beginning of my updated answer. The KeyError relates to the way you're accessing the dataframe. It is not related to the second issue (iterating over the characters)

Comment: Just to make sure I understand correctly. Are you referring to the start of my function defintion, where I say `for elements in auto[i,date_column]:`. Thanks for the answer, It has cleared up a few misconceptions.

Comment: Yes, this is the place I refer to in explaining the reason for the KeyError. Only if you change it to `auto.loc[...` the code can run without error, but you get something different from what you wanted (iterating over chars instead of rows).

Answer (score 0):

You can transform these columns to a DateTime column and drop the time using `pd.to_datetime(column).dt.date`:

```
df[['date_crawled', 'ad_created', 'last_seen']] = df[['date_crawled', 'ad_created', 'last_seen']].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).dt.date)
df
# date_crawled  ad_created  last_seen
# 0 2016-03-24  2016-03-24  2016-04-07
# 1 2016-03-24  2016-03-24  2016-04-07
# 2 2016-03-14  2016-03-14  2016-04-05
# 3 2016-03-17  2016-03-17  2016-03-17
# 4 2016-03-31  2016-03-31  2016-04-06
```

Comment: He wants to format the date as "%d-%m-%Y", not just dropping the time part

Comment: Who cares about the date format? That's a matter for printing or saving the data.

Comment: I don't care, just refering to the original request :)